# How do I properly split a PATH variable in PHP?

Tags: php, path, operating-system, variables, environment

I want to split

```
$path = getenv('PATH');
```

into its components. How do I determine the separator char in an os-dependent fashion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant, then the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to split the path if needed.
See [`Directory Predefined Constants`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

Comment: You cannot use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` for that. You must use `PATH_SEPARATOR`. First one is the character that separates folders from each other, path separator separates differents paths i.e. defined in PATH environmental variable.

Comment: @Greg, ? Would you at least clean up the mistake or delete the answer so that others below can get rightful attention? Your answer with 18 upvotes is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant.

Answer (score 3):

I know this works for the include_path - not sure about getenv('PATH'):

```
$paths = split(PATH_SEPARATOR, getenv('PATH'));
```

Comment: include_path is a valid PATH style string for whatever system you are on: the same split techniques that work for one will work for the other.

Comment: Note that this post was written in 2009. `split()` has been deprecated according to the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that Windows will accept both forward- and back-slashes as a file-separator, so you may not have to worry about it.

Comment: I think he means the separator for the Entries in the PATH environment variable (e.g. ":" on *nix), not the separator inside the paths.