# How to get a platform independent directory separator in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, filepath

I'm building a path string in PHP. I need it to work across platforms (i.e., Linux, Windows, OS X). 
I'm doing this:

```
$path = $someDirectory.'/'.$someFile;
```

Assume `$someDirectory` and `$someFile` are formatted correctly at run-time on the various platforms. This works beautifully on Linux and OS X, but not on Windows. The issue is the `/` character, which I thought would work for Windows.

Is there a PHP function or some other trick to switch this to `\` at runtime on Windows?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, the resultant string is

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Sitefusion\Sitefusion.org\Defaults\pref/user.preferences
```

on Windows. Obviously the mix of slashes confuses Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly split a PATH variable in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259450/how-do-i-properly-split-a-path-variable-in-php)

Comment: Worth to mention: Windows works fine when using `/` as directory separator. There is usually no need to make it platform dependent. I don't know, what you mean with "the mix [..] confuses Windows"

Comment: Thanks, @AJ. I missed that question.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Try this one

DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

```
$patch = $somePath. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$someFile
```

or you can define yours

```
PHP_OS == "Windows" ||
    PHP_OS == "WINNT" ? define("SEPARATOR", "\\") : define("SEPARATOR", "/");
```

Comment: No joy, this gives me the same string on Windows. I tried PATH_SEPARATOR, too.

Comment: however,  both, Windows and Linux supports / so what's problem ?

Comment: The problem in my instance is I'm getting the first half of the path ($someDirectory) dynamically (from XULRunner) which uses '\' on Windows. PHP is giving '/' and Windows barfs at the slash combination.

Comment: @retrodone: You should describe, what happens instead. What (in your case) does "barfs at the slash combination" mean? You may add it to your question. I'm starting to think, that the `/` isn't the real problem.

Comment: @King: I think that he gets C:\path\to\his\dir/but/now/there/is/dynamic/dir and he don't want to mash it up

Comment: Why would `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` return `/` on his Windows box?

Comment: @KingCrunch, I get the following error from XULRunner: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://sitefusion/content/sitefusion.js -> resource://sflibcache/class/fileHandling.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 125"  data: no]

Comment: It's the JavaScript generated by PHP. I'm using SiteFusion.

Comment: Instead of "Windows" my server resturn "WINNT". Just in case.

Comment: **Don't bother**, this IS NOT necessary.

Comment: Not that it's critically important, but `PATH_SEPARATOR` is something else entirely (`:` on *nix, `;` on Windows) and isn't a synonym of `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: @retrodrone just parse your input then, split it by directory separator, and then reconstitute it using a single directory separator.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')           
    define("SEPARATOR", "\\");
else 
    define("SEPARATOR", "/");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php