# How to check if my php version is going to understand DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR if its version dependent

Tags: php, directory

I am not sure about which platform my code goes to host, so im using directory separator in my code.

I followed this link - [how-to-get-a-platform-independent-directory-separator-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654157/how-to-get-a-platform-independent-directory-separator-in-php)

but the accepted answer is not what i am looking (string replacement). Although another solution with "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" is something what I was looking for but my concern is when i checked the docs at -> [dir.constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)

They said - `The constants below are defined by this extension, and will only be available when the extension has either been compiled into PHP or dynamically loaded at runtime.`

So from where I can check whether this extension is available or not, I checked from `phpinfo()` method but unable to locate under it, how can I locate this whether installed or not ? . If its available in all so can i proceed with this dummy code or not -

```
$headurl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.'backgroundimage.jpg';
```

Comment: Both unix and windows support `/` so it's safe just to use that for everything. Only time you have to be careful is if you are manipulating (ie comparing/exploding) paths since windows will have `\ ` by default and unix will have `/`.

Comment: @Supericy thx for the info & what about checking for directory structure constant whether supported or not ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These constants are extension dependent but its part of PHP now. See [dir.installation](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.installation.php).

> There is no installation needed to use these functions; **they are part of the PHP core**.

Even in [requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.requirements.php) Its stated

> No external libraries are needed to build this extension.

So you dont have to worry about it. Every platform will support this constant

Answer (score 3):

**DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** is predefined constant and available in all PHP versions right from the start to ensure cross OS file system compatibility. you can use it.

note: this is also indicated in your reference http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php (by the missing *"Available since PHP x.x.x."*. e.g. PATH_SEPARATOR is *"Available since PHP 4.3.0."*).

Comment: yeah thx for mentioning...what i was looking at Director Separator so just forgot to read the lower one ..my bad :( +1