# how to access the file

Tags: php, laravel, apache

In LAN win 7 on a virtual machine under win 10, Apache launched a program on Laravel. How can I get access to a specific local network file from the program code?
I try to use a symbolic link to the folder where the file is located, function `file_exists(symbolic_link_path . '/' . file_name)` notifies that there is no such file.

Comment: If you're using linux, then the paths use `/`, not `\\`

Comment: Looks like a UNC.  Does the apache user have permissions to `\\myserv\myfile.txt`?

Comment: Also, in double quotes you need to double up the slashes.

Comment: Try echoing `dir .symbolic_folder_link_name where_file is. '/' .filename`, and look at that exact path yourself to see if the file is there.

Comment: file access available

Comment: Windows file systems don't typically support symbolic links.

Comment: symbolic link created. Going into it, I see the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use the PHP variable "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" instead of "/" (that is supported globally).
Here you can find another similar topic about splitting paths: [How do I properly split a PATH variable in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259450/how-do-i-properly-split-a-path-variable-in-php)

If you want to debug the path inserted, I suggest you to print the result of the function "[is_file($filepath)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)" ("[is_dir($dirpath)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)" in case of directories): if the result is true, then the path is correct. If the result is false, the path has something wrong.

Comment: \Log::info(is_file(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . symbolic_link_name . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . file_name)?'yes':'no') return 'no'